# I started passenger on bluehost now i want to stop it it giving me error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

i want to get the passenger port to stop it which it is running.
when i run passenger stop command i gives me following error.

```
Phusion Passenger Standalone is not running, according to PID file /home/user1/rails_apps/redmine/public/passenger.3000.pid
```

how i can stop the running passenger ?[image]

this is snapshot of running passenger

Answer (score 0):

You usually do `passenger stop -p 8000` (first `cd` to the dir you started the process from)

If that will not work, either do passenger `stop --pid-file <path-to-PID-file>` (usually resides in `/tmp`) or remove the PID file.